# What are the differences between MockBackend and HttpTestingController?

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

When testing Angular services, when might I use `HttpTestingController.expectOne(...).flush(...)` or similar, and when would it be better to use `MockBackend.connections.subscribe(...)`. Are these just a matter of preference or are there clear use cases that lend themselves to one approach over the other?

Answer (score 0):

`MockBackend` was deprecated in Angular 4 and removed in Angular 7 together with the whole `HttpModule`. `HttpTestingController` is the new counterpart of `MockBackend` that comes from the new `HttpClientModule`.

You can read a more detailed documentation about the new module and it's testing facilities on the [official Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#setup-for-testing).